# How to keep whitespaces in XSLT

Tags: templates, xslt

I have a XSLT file in which I have HTML code with some XSLT tags. I have one `xsl:template` in it. Everything is fine until I call `xsl:apply-templates`. After that there is *no* whitespaces between html tags in resulting file. They are all concatenated.

How I can force XSLT to keep my format of HTML code, to include tabs and newlines between HTML tags?

`xsl:preserve-space` is used for preserving space from the XML data file. I need to preserve space in HTML i.e. XSLT stylesheet. I tried with `xsl:call-template`, but the same thing happened.

====================================

So, I striped away a lot of code that is not needed to illustrate the problem that I have. This is .xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet  [
    <!ENTITY nbsp " ">
    <!ENTITY copy  "©">
]>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"&gt;
    </xsl:text>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

        <head>
            <xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if gte mso 9]><xml>
            <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG/>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
            </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            </xml><![endif]]]></xsl:comment>
            <title>Test</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 " />
            <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>

            <xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if !mso]><!]]></xsl:comment>

            <xsl:comment><![CDATA[<![endif]]]></xsl:comment>

        </head>

        <body class="em_body" style="margin:0px auto; padding:0px;" bgcolor="#4070d0">

        <xsl:comment>****  H E A D E R   ***** </xsl:comment>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_full_wrap" bgcolor="#4070d0">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_main_table" style="width:600px; table-layout:fixed;">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:15px 6px 14px 10px;" class="em_ptrbl"><table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top">

                                            <xsl:comment><![CDATA[[if gte mso 9]></td><td valign="top"><![endif]]]></xsl:comment>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <xsl:comment>*******    C O N T E N T   **** </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:for-each select="New/Deals/Deal"> 

            <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                <xsl:with-param name="levelCount" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="lastCount" select="last()" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>      

        </xsl:for-each>


        <xsl:comment>*****  F O O T E R     *****</xsl:comment>


    </body>
    </html>


    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="Deal" name="dealTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="levelCount"/>
    <xsl:param name="lastCount"/>

    <xsl:if test="($levelCount - 1) mod 4 = 0">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_full_wrap" bgcolor="#4070d0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_main_table" style="width:600px; table-layout:fixed;">]]>
            </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="$levelCount=1">
        <xsl:comment> [IMAGE: HERO BANNER] </xsl:comment>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[
    <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="center" class="em_aside5">
                <table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" align="left" bgcolor="#254c9a" style="padding:12px 10px; border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:22px; font-weight:bold; color:#ffffff;">Featured deals</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:comment>
    ******  D E A L *******</xsl:comment>
    <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="em_plrt">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$levelCount=0">padding:18px 14px 0px 14px;</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>padding:12px 14px 0px 14px;</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:attribute>
            <table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" align="center">
                        <table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <xsl:comment> [HEADLINE] </xsl:comment>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" align="left" class="em_blue" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color: #3158aa; font-size:18px; line-height:22px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:12px;">
                                    <a style="color: #3158aa;  text-decoration: none;" target="_blank">
                                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                            <xsl:value-of select="Url"/>
                                        </xsl:attribute>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Headline"/>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <xsl:if test="($levelCount - 1) mod 4 = 3 or $levelCount = $lastCount">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>]]>             
            </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And source file, my data file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<New>
    <Deals>
        <Deal>
        <Price>$115+</Price>
        <Headline>Save 70% + Up to $400</Headline>
        <Url>https://www.yahoo.com/</Url>
    </Deal>
    Deal>
        <Price>$115+</Price>
        <Headline>Save 70% + Up to $400</Headline>
        <Url>https://www.yahoo.com/</Url>
    </Deal>
    <Deal>
        <Price>$115+</Price>
        <Headline>Save 70% + Up to $400</Headline>
        <Url>https://www.yahoo.com/</Url>
    </Deal>
    <Deal>
        <Price>$115+</Price>
        <Headline>Save 70% + Up to $400</Headline>
        <Url>https://www.yahoo.com/</Url>
    </Deal>
    <Deal>
        <Price>$115+</Price>
        <Headline>Save 70% + Up to $400</Headline>
        <Url>https://www.yahoo.com/</Url>
    </Deal>
    </Deals>
</New>
```

Their request was that every 4 deals have their table, so this strange maths in xsl:if
And resulting html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <head>
        <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
            <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG/>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
            </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            </xml><![endif]-->
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 " />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <!--<![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body class="em_body" style="margin:0px auto; padding:0px;" bgcolor="#4070d0">
        <!--****  H E A D E R   ***** -->
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_full_wrap" bgcolor="#4070d0">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                    <table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_main_table" style="width:600px; table-layout:fixed;">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" align="center" style="padding:15px 6px 14px 10px;" class="em_ptrbl">
                                <table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td valign="top">
                                            <!--[if gte mso 9]></td><td valign="top"><![endif]-->
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--******* C O N T E N T   **** --><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_full_wrap" bgcolor="#4070d0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_main_table" style="width:600px; table-layout:fixed;">
            <!-- [IMAGE: HERO BANNER] -->
      <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="center" class="em_aside5">
                <table width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" align="left" bgcolor="#254c9a" style="padding:12px 10px; border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:22px; font-weight:bold; color:#ffffff;">Featured deals</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr><!--
  ******    D E A L  *******--><tr><td valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="em_plrt" style="padding:12px 14px 0px 14px;"><table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td valign="top" align="center"><table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><!-- [HEADLINE] --><tr><td valign="top" align="left" class="em_blue" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color: #3158aa; font-size:18px; line-height:22px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:12px;"><a style="color: #3158aa;  text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="https://www.yahoo.com/">$115+Save 70% + Up to $400</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><!--
  ******    D E A L  *******--><tr><td valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="em_plrt" style="padding:12px 14px 0px 14px;"><table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td valign="top" align="center"><table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><!-- [HEADLINE] --><tr><td valign="top" align="left" class="em_blue" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color: #3158aa; font-size:18px; line-height:22px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:12px;"><a style="color: #3158aa;  text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="https://www.yahoo.com/">$115+Save 70% + Up to $400</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><!--
  ******    D E A L  *******--><tr><td valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="em_plrt" style="padding:12px 14px 0px 14px;"><table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td valign="top" align="center"><table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><!-- [HEADLINE] --><tr><td valign="top" align="left" class="em_blue" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color: #3158aa; font-size:18px; line-height:22px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:12px;"><a style="color: #3158aa;  text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="https://www.yahoo.com/">$115+Save 70% + Up to $400</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><!--
  ******    D E A L  *******--><tr><td valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="em_plrt" style="padding:12px 14px 0px 14px;"><table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td valign="top" align="center"><table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><!-- [HEADLINE] --><tr><td valign="top" align="left" class="em_blue" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color: #3158aa; font-size:18px; line-height:22px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:12px;"><a style="color: #3158aa;  text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="https://www.yahoo.com/">$115+Save 70% + Up to $400</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_full_wrap" bgcolor="#4070d0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top">
                            <table align="center" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="em_main_table" style="width:600px; table-layout:fixed;">
            <!--
  ******    D E A L  *******--><tr><td valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="em_plrt" style="padding:12px 14px 0px 14px;"><table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td valign="top" align="center"><table align="center" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><!-- [HEADLINE] --><tr><td valign="top" align="left" class="em_blue" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; color: #3158aa; font-size:18px; line-height:22px; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:12px;"><a style="color: #3158aa;  text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" href="https://www.yahoo.com/">$115+Save 70% + Up to $400</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                
            <!--*****  F O O T E R      *****--></body>
</html>
```

So, my problem is with these connected html elements (without whitespaces between them, as it is determined in .xslt file), starting with **** Deal ***. HTML is well formated outside xsl:template i.e. before I call apply-templates. I tried with xml:space="preserve" in many places, and conditions, but nothing helped.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried `<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes">`?

Comment: Yes, I have that in my code. It's like something with calling xsl template break identation

Comment: Well, there is `xml:space="preserve"` in XML and XSLT is XML so perhaps that helps: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-white-space and https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#stylesheet-stripping give more details. But post minimal but complete details of XML, XSLT, output you get and the one you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xml:space="preserve"` on an element in the stylesheet, but beware of consequences. It may cause whitespace to appear where you don't want it in the rendered output, for example

```
<xsl:value-of select="'('"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$word"/>
<xsl:value-of select="')'"/>
```

would render as `( word )` when you probably wanted `(word)`.

Similarly, writing

```
<xsl:element name="a">
  <xsl:attribute name="b">xx</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

would cause a failure because you are writing a child node (containing whitespace text) to the element before you create its attribute node.

Using `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>` to inject new whitespace into the output is probably a better way of getting readable HTML output.

Comment: I have xsl:output. I tried xml:space and it works on <tr>s which don't have xslt elements. If I use with those that contains xsl:attribute (as I use only them) I receive error: 
_Attribute and namespace nodes cannot be added to the parent element after a text, comment, pi, or sub-element node has already been added_

I will try now to create minimal example, to try to figure out what is wrong and than to post here.
Thanks.

Comment: @Garvan - As Michael Kay says, you need to beware of the consequences. If you have used `xsl:attribute` and have `xml:space="preserve"` or the parent element, then any whitespace before `xsl:attribute` will be added as a child text node. It is then an error to try adding an attribute after adding a child node. The solution could be to either remove any whitespace before the `xsl:attribute`, or maybe make use of [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#attribute-value-templates) to create them instead.

Comment: @Garvan Thanks, I added a second example of what can go wrong if you use the xml:space approach.